# db2level on aix not working

Tags: db2, aix

db2 => db2level
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003

what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db2level` is an OS command, not a DB2 CLP command.

```
$ which db2level
/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2level
$ which db2
/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2
```